# PHP update undefine

Tags: php, mysql

Não consigo fazer o Update na base de dados

**faltas.php**

```php
<?php
if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Comandante"){
    if(isset($_POST['estadoComando'])){
        updater($_POST['estadoComando'],$_POST['id']); //<-- linha 213
    }
    function updater($value,$id){
        // Create connection
        //$conn = new mysqli( 'fdb17.awardspace.net' , '2544173_bvmarco' , 'mox1244200' ,'2544173_bvmarco' );
        $conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'bvmarco' );
        $value =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
        $id =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
        // Check connection
        $estadoComando=$_POST['estacoComando'];
            $IDS=$_POST['id'];
            $dataComando=$_POST['dataComando'];
            $sql = "UPDATE `faltas` SET `dataComando`='{$dataComando}' `estadoComando`='{$estadoComando}' WHERE `Id`='{$IDS}'";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade-in">';
                echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
                echo '  <strong>Enviado!</strong>';
                echo '</div>';
            }else{
                echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable fade-in">';
                echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
                echo '  <strong>ERRO!</strong> Algo correu mal comunique com o developer.';
                echo '</div>';
                }
        $conn->close();
    }
}else{
    if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Direccao"){
        if(isset($_POST['estado'])){
            updater($_POST['estadoDirecao'],$_POST['id']);<--line 213
        }
        function updater($value,$id){
            // Create connection
            //$conn = new mysqli( 'fdb17.awardspace.net' , '2544173_bvmarco' , 'mox1244200' ,'2544173_bvmarco' );
            $conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'bvmarco' );
            $value =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
            $id =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $estadoDirecao=$_POST['estacoDirecao'];
            $IDS=$_POST['id'];
            $dataDirecao=$_POST['dataComando'];
            $sql = "UPDATE `faltas` SET `dataDirecao`='{$dataDirecao}' `estadoDirecao`='{$estadoDirecao}' WHERE `Id`='{$IDS}'";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade-in">';
                echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
                echo '  <strong>Enviado!</strong>';
                echo '</div>';
            }else{
                echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable fade-in">';
                echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
                echo '  <strong>ERRO!</strong> Algo correu mal comunique com o developer.';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function updater() in D:\wamp64\www\bvmarco\faltas.php on line 213

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="jumbotron">
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Numero</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Nome</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Nº Interno</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Categoria</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Tipo de falta</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Datas</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Horas</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Motivo</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Documentos</th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Data inserção</th>
        <?php 
            if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Comandante"){
                echo '<th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Estado Direcção</th>';
                echo '<th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Motivo Direcção</th>';
            }if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Direccao"){
                echo '<th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Estado Comando</th>';
                echo '<th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Motivo</th>';
            }
        ?>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Estado</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php do { ?>
        <form id="estado" name="estado" action="" method="post">
            <tbody>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['Id']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['nome']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['numInterno']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['categoria']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['falta']; ?></td>
                        <?php
                            $dataDe=$row_faltas['dataDe'];
                            $dataEm=$row_faltas['dataEm'];
                            $dataAte=$row_faltas['dataAte'];
                            $horaDe=$row_faltas['horaDe'];
                            $horaAte=$row_faltas['horaAte'];
                            if($dataEm == NULL){
                                echo'<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">'.$dataDe.'/'.$dataAte.'</td>';
                                echo'<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"></td>';
                            }else{
                                if($dataDe == NULL){
                                    echo'<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">'.$dataEm.'</td>';
                                    echo'<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">'.$horaDe.'/'.$horaAte.'</td>';
                                }else{
                                    echo'<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"></td>';
                                    echo'<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"></td>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['motivo']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['documentos']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo $row_faltas['data']; ?></td>
                        <?php
                            if($row_faltas['estadoComando']=="1"){
                                echo '<td class="text-info" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><strong>Em espera</strong></td>';
                            }else{
                                if($row_faltas['estadoComando']=="2"){
                                    echo '<td class="text-success" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><strong>Autoriza</strong></td>';
                                }else{
                                    if($row_faltas['estadoComando']=="3"){
                                        echo '<td  class="text-danger"style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><strong>Não Autoriza</strong></td>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                            $tipo=$row_faltas['tipo'];
                            if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Comandante"){
                                echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">'.$tipo.'</td>';
                            }else{
                                if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Direccao"){
                                    echo'<td  class="text-danger"style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
                                            <option></option>
                                            <option>Férias</option>
                                            <option>Falta just. c/ renumeração</option>
                                            <option>Falta just. s/ renumeração</option>
                                            <option>Falta injustificada</option>
                                        </select></td>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                            <?php
                                if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Comandante"){
                                    if($row_faltas['estadoComando'] == "1"){
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="'.$row_faltas['Id'].'" />';
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="dataComando" nome="dataComando" value"'.date("d-m-Y").'"/>';
                                        echo '<button name="estadoComando" id="estadoComando" type="submit" class="btn success2" value="2">Sim</button>';
                                        echo '<button name="estadoComando" id="estadocomando" type="submit" class="btn danger2" value="3">Não</button>';
                                    }else{
                                        if($row_faltas['estadoComando'] == "2"){
                                            echo '<p class="text-success"><b>Autorizado</b></p>';
                                        }else{
                                            if($row_faltas['estadoComando'] == "2"){
                                                echo '<p class="text-danger"><b>Não Autorizado</b></p>';
                                            }else{
                                                echo'';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    if($row_faltas['estadoDirecao'] == "1"){
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="'.$row_faltas['Id'].'" />';
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="dataComando" nome="dataDirecao" value"'.date("d-m-Y").'"/>';
                                        echo '<button name="estadoDirecao" id="estadoDirecao" type="submit" class="btn success2" value="2">Sim</button>';
                                        echo '<button name="estadoDirecao" id="estadoDirecao" type="submit" class="btn danger2" value="3">Não</button>';
                                    }else{
                                        if($row_faltas['estadoDirecao'] == "2"){
                                            echo '<p class="text-success"><b>Autorizado</b></p>';
                                        }else{
                                            if($row_faltas['estadoDirecao'] == "3"){
                                                echo'<p class="text-success"><b>Não Autorizado</b></p>';
                                            }else{
                                                echo'';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Direccao"){
                    echo'<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td class=""><strong>Despacho</strong></td>
                        <td colspan="12"><input type="text" name="despacho" class="form-control col" required></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>';
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </form>
     <?php } while ($row_faltas = mysql_fetch_assoc($faltas)); ?>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta precisa ter conteúdo, você precisa contextualizar o que está fazendo, e qual seu problema e o que você já tentou até agora, e só depois mostrar o seu código e o erro que está gerando.

Comment: Assim já se consegue perceber? Se for preciso alterar ou acrescentar algo para se perceber diga que eu faço

Comment: Qual é o arquivo `faltas.php`?  Onde é a linha `213`? Com esse código fica difícil identificar o problema, tenta colocar só o necessário para reproduzir o  erro

Comment: o arquivo faltas.php foi o que eu coloquei ai e a linha 213 acabei de identificar como comentario //<-- linha213

Comment: Não vai funcionar, você está chamando a função antes dela existir, você precisa criar a função antes de chamá-la

Comment: Como assim? como o devo fazer

Eu tenho a função mas mais resumida noutro ficheiro e funciona

Comment: Faz igual nesse [link](https://gist.github.com/denisrudnei/f9ec2cac3fdbb289e495aa521b518281)

Comment: Uma dica daqui do site, quando responder alguém via comentário, coloca @ junto com o nome da pessoa para que a mesma receba uma notificação, só vi que você respondeu por que eu recarreguei a página, o único que não precisa ser mencionado para receber a notificação é o autor da pergunta

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza agora aparece este erro
 Notice: Undefined index: dataComando que provem do codigo $dataComando=$_POST['dataComando'];

Comment: Você acessou diretamente o arquivo? Se sim vai dar esse erro, só vai existir se você mandar uma requisição *POST* para a página em questão, aconselho você a tentar dar uma revisada no código, acho que o problema é a forma como foi escrito

Comment: já alterei o código mas não me faz o update e não dá nenhum erro
@DenisRudneideSouza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você estava usando uma estrutura confusa (usando duas funções com o mesmo nome para coisas diferentes) em vez de simplificar criando duas funções com nomes diferentes (embora seja possivel unifica-las em uma só). Então, mudei o nome de uma das funções `updater`  para `updaterComando()` e a outra para `updaterDirecao()`, e as colocando fora dos laços if (É claro que pode haver algum erro sintatico!). Depois disso ficou assim:

```
<?php

function updaterComando($value,$id){
    // Create connection
    //$conn = new mysqli( 'fdb17.awardspace.net' , '2544173_bvmarco' , 'mox1244200' ,'2544173_bvmarco' );
    $conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'bvmarco' );
    $value =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
    $id =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
    // Check connection
    $estadoComando=$_POST['estacoComando'];
        $IDS=$_POST['id'];
        $dataComando=$_POST['dataComando'];
        $sql = "UPDATE `faltas` SET `dataComando`='{$dataComando}' `estadoComando`='{$estadoComando}' WHERE `Id`='{$IDS}'";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade-in">';
            echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
            echo '  <strong>Enviado!</strong>';
            echo '</div>';
        }else{
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable fade-in">';
            echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
            echo '  <strong>ERRO!</strong> Algo correu mal comunique com o developer.';
            echo '</div>';
            }
    $conn->close();
}

function updaterDirecao($value,$id){
    // Create connection
    //$conn = new mysqli( 'fdb17.awardspace.net' , '2544173_bvmarco' , 'mox1244200' ,'2544173_bvmarco' );
    $conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'bvmarco' );
    $value =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
    $id =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $estadoDirecao=$_POST['estacoDirecao'];
    $IDS=$_POST['id'];
    $dataDirecao=$_POST['dataComando'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `faltas` SET `dataDirecao`='{$dataDirecao}' `estadoDirecao`='{$estadoDirecao}' WHERE `Id`='{$IDS}'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade-in">';
        echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
        echo '  <strong>Enviado!</strong>';
        echo '</div>';
    }else{
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable fade-in">';
        echo '  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
        echo '  <strong>ERRO!</strong> Algo correu mal comunique com o developer.';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $conn->close();
}

if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Comandante"){
    if(isset($_POST['estadoComando'])){
        updaterComando($_POST['estadoComando'],$_POST['id']);
    }  
}else{
    if($_SESSION['MM_Username']=="Direccao"){
        if(isset($_POST['estado'])){
            updaterDirecao($_POST['estadoDirecao'],$_POST['id']);
        }       
    }
}
?>
```